# Can I move WordPress to another folder?

Tags: hosting

My client has a very bare bones host who would not allow installation of WP. They insisted on doing it and in that process installed the files in a subfolder rather than at the top level.

The question is, can I simply move the file to the top level and expect WP to run, or is there pathway information in the database?

Answer (score 2):

You can follow the Wordpress docs and leave Wordpress in a directory but have it appear to be in root. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory#Using_a_pre-existing_subdirectory_install

This will correctly change the location in the database. This might be the best way to go if the host requires Wordpress to be in a subfolder for some reason.

[image]

> **Or, you can move all the files to root.** See http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress **This link also includes
>   recovery information in case you make mistakes in the move.**